# Polling a process every X seconds with low CPU usage

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, polling

I basically need to run this code every 5 seconds or so:

```
if (oneperone.HasExited)
{
    oneperone.Start();
}
foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WerFault"))
{
    try
    {
        p.Kill();
        p.WaitForExit(); // possibly with a timeout
    }
    catch (Win32Exception winException)
    {
        // process was terminating or can't be terminated - deal with it
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException invalidException)
    {
        // process has already exited - might be able to let this one go
    }
}
```

I've tried using a timer with the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx and I've tried running an infinite loop with system thread wait commands but both give unacceptable performance and the system wait command obviously locks up the thread I need to do other things in between the 5 second iteration

keep in mind the 5 seconds thing is arbitrary it can be longer or shorter I just need to keep repeating this code but efficiently hopefully someone has a graceful solution?

Comment: you can use a parallel foreach so you stop multiple processes at same time and overall execution time will be shorter

Comment: @arcaine: what will happen if from (say) 5 processes the 3rd one, for any reason runs for more then 5 seconds? Should it be killed so another should start?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, the oneperone is a program that needs to be running all the time, WerFault is the crash process, you cannot bring a oneperone process online if it has crashed because .HasExited does not trigger during a crash to side step this I'm checking for the crash process and killing it to allow for a new reboot

Comment: just to remind everyone I'm interested in running this code once every X amount of seconds efficiently not so much the content of the code because that's subject to change once I have the polling ready anyway

Comment: Any performance issue will be in the calls to class Process. not in the waiting or Timer code.

Comment: How does a Timer give unaccaptable performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely better way to achieve what you need, but here is suggestion for what you want:

Thread.Sleep will give you low CPU usage as long as you don't do long end expensive operations on each iteration.

Create new thread with Sleep calls and queue up processes to kill in some queue (to avoid long operations on this thread and duplication of "kill requests"); kill processes from the queue on separate thread/worker. Avoid attempting to kill the same process more than once.